# Download files from an array from SFTP server using WinSCP in PowerShell only when the files exist

Tags: .net, powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I have this PowerShell code.

I have a little problem:

- I download two remote files `Device.log` and `Saveinfo.dat`; Not all machines have both `device.log` and `saveinfo.dat`. Some machines have only `device.log` and when I try on machine what have only `device.log` the script fails. What can I do?
- If machine have both file archive together and if machine have only `device.log` archive only that file (`device.log`).

Thank you

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"
 
$db = import-csv -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\db.csv"
 
$inputID = Read-Host -Prompt "ID"
 
$entry = $db -match $inputID

Write-Host "IP:" $entry.IP

    $User = "user"
    $Password = "password"
    $Command = "C:\SaveBVInfo.exe"

    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $secpasswd)

Get-SSHTrustedHost | Remove-SSHTrustedHost

$SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $entry.IP -Credential $Credentials -AcceptKey:$true

Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $sessionid.sessionid -Command $Command

# Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = $entry.IP
    UserName = "$User"
    Password = "$Password"
    GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = "true"
}
 
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

$file = "Device.log", "SaveBVInfo.dat"
$localPath = "E:\loguri\Log\Arhive\*"
$remotePath = "/C:/Program Files/Common Files/logs/Device.log", "/C:/Program Files/Pc/SaveBVInfo.dat"
 
try {

    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Check files exists
 
        if ($session.FileExists($remotePath))
        {
            Write-Host "File $remotePath exists"
            # Transfer files

            $session.GetFiles($remotePath, $localPath).Check()
 
            exit 0
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "File $remotePath does not exist"
            exit 1
        }
}
finally {
    $session.Dispose()
}
foreach ($file in "E:\loguri\Log\Arhive\Device.log", "E:\loguri\Log\Arhive\SaveBVInfo.dat") {
    Compress-Archive $file -DestinationPath "E:\Arhive\$inputID.zip" -Update
    Remove-Item $file -Force
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass PowerShell arrays to .NET methods that do not take arrays.

You have to process your files in a loop:

```
$remotePaths = "/C:/Program Files/Common Files/logs/Device.log", "/C:/Program Files/Pc/SaveBVInfo.dat"
```

```
foreach ($remotePath in $remotePaths)
{
    if ($session.FileExists($remotePath))
    {
        Write-Host "File $remotePath exists"
        # Transfer files

        $session.GetFiles($remotePath, $localPath).Check()
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "File $remotePath does not exist"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does the script fail?  I can see two places where you assume the files exist.  Before you call `$session.GetFiles()` you should surely call `$session.FileExists()` first to verify that it's there.  See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_checking_file_existence

Secondly, your `Test-Path` will be true if either file is present but then you add both to the archive regardless of whether there was just one.  Check for each file and then add it.

```
foreach ($file in "E:\Arhive\Device.log", "E:\Arhive\Saveinfo.dat") {
    if (Test-Path $file) {
        Compress-Archive $file -DestinationPath "E:\Arhive\$inputID.zip" -Update
        Remove-Item $file
     }
}
```

Comment: Hello Mark, first of all thank's again for your help. I edit my question with updated scripts but something goes wrong...

Comment: Hi, where does it go wrong?  Your try block will never get anywhere because both of your paths have an `exit`.  Try removing `exit 0` in the case where the file exists, and move the `exit 1` to the finally block.

Comment: I fix that problem. (Martin script)
Whatever your Compress-Archive works very well but if I have only Device.log for archive , the script archive ok but return code Saveinfo.dat is missing or something like that. Can I fix this minor Issue ? (i hate red) :)) (Something like this , if Saveinfo.dat does not exist please except it without output error code) Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I've added a `Test-Path` into the loop which should get rid of the red.

Comment: Great, now it's works very well. Thank you again Mark.